# Office Communicator only displays a partial screen when sharing desktop

Tags: office-communicator-2007

I'm supporting a user in another state and when I ask them to share their screen with me, it only displays part of the screen.

They have 2 screens, for simplicity's sake, lets say they're both 1000 x 800 (2000 x 800 total). It will show a rectangle that is ~1200 x ~600. This feature works great on all other user's machines.

Are there any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have set the text size to Larger (150%). I changed this to Medium (125%) which required a log off/log in and it resolved the problem.

The setting is found under:

> Control Panel - All Control Panel Items - Display